# Adding Owner attribute in playwright junit report

Tags: junit, playwright, playwright-test

I have playwright test suite and I configured it to produce test report in junit format.
I publish the result in ADO and I want to export Owner field in pipeline test report [image: ado report showing owner]

According to [this azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=junit%2Cyaml) document, I have to provide an owner attribute.

I want to have Owner attribute in my junit xml output file like this bold text.
e.g
<testcase name="Navigation demo" classname="modules\my.spec.ts:14:5 › Demo desc  › Demo test" time="20.413" **Owner='purchase management'**>

I looked at source code of playwright [junit reporter](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/3dc1920ce83b56a408d84e2d43e07ec8976d924d/packages/playwright-test/src/reporters/junit.ts#L132).
It seems it's hardcoded 3 attributes. So, I am not sure how to add owner attribute there.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Hi @hasan.in, did you figure this out? I'm also trying to populate the "Owner" column in my Azure DevOps platform, and i'm also using playwright to run the tests but i don't know how to add an owner tag to each test :(

Comment: Yes, Its possible when we write custom reporter. I'll share sample code

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it, I'm still trying to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

I've been also trying to figure this out. Extending the reporter using Xray only adds a properties tag which can't be consumed by Azure Devops.

Edit:

I was playing around with using a [custom playwright reporter](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#custom-reporters) and got this to work. Follow the steps to create a custom reporter and copy their built-in JUnit reporter to your reporter. Change the class name to whatever and then use these imports:

```
 import fs from 'fs';
 import path from 'path';
 import type { FullConfig, FullResult, Reporter, Suite, TestCase } from '@playwright/test/reporter';
 import { monotonicTime } from 'playwright-core/lib/utils';
 import { formatFailure, formatTestTitle, stripAnsiEscapes } from '../../node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/reporters/base';
```

From there you can then edit and add attributes however you'd like:

```
       attributes: {    
         // Skip root, project, file
         name: test.titlePath().slice(3).join(' '),
         classname: formatTestTitle(this.config, test),
         time: (test.results.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value.duration, 0)) / 1000,
         owner: 'TEST_STRING'
       },
```

Comment: Hi @Joeflan any chance you could elaborate on this? I tried making a class that implements Reporter but the only methods in Reporter that I can see are onBegin, onTestBegin, onTestEnd and onEnd, not "attributes"